# vs2017 creates empty IISExpress folder for C# ASP.NET MVC projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I had run vs2013, vs2015, and now vs2017, yet this error cannot go away. I later check the IISExpress directory in my documents directory (C:\users\~useraccount\Documents \IISExpress\config)
was empty!
In fact the 3 folders in IISExpress directory are all empty, that is: config, logs, and TraceaLogFiles.

I have tried many solutions here, but none has worked.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you run VS in administrator role?

Comment: Yes I have multiple times. That too didn't help.